# How to ask the user to specify a folder name (using Inno Setup)?

Tags: inno-setup

I have to install an application that relies on a web server (XAMPP), so I'd like to add to my setup wizard a form that notifies the user if a given folder (of XAMPP) does not exist, then to provide a textbox and to ask the user to specify a folder name where this web server is installed.

I'd like to keep this folder name as a variable, since later I have to place some files in that folder.

Can you guide me how to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`CreateInputDirPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage) to create the page/form.

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to install the files to the selected folder.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "somefile.txt"; DestDir: "{code:GetOtherDir}"

[Code]

var
  OtherInputDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  OtherInputDirPage :=
    CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir, 'Select xampp directory', '', '', False, '');
  OtherInputDirPage.Add('');
end;

function GetOtherDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := OtherInputDirPage.Values[0];
end;
```

You should add some validation.

See also the article [Prompt for an additional folder for data](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309062208/http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Prompt_for_an_additional_folder_for_data) on ISXKB.