# Leave Inno Setup DefaultDirName empty or with message "choose install directory"

Tags: inno-setup

I made a plugin for 3ds Max and I need two things:

- A message *"Choose your 3ds Max root"* in the path field in place of "c:... or d:...".
- I also need that the *Next* button can't be clicked, if the user didn't choose the path manually with the *Browse* button.

Thanks much.

Comment: and what have you done up till now, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

- Clear the `DirEdit` in [`InitializeWizard` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard). You probably want to clear it on first install only, not on re-install/upgrade. Inno Setup itself will not allow user to proceed, unless user selects the path.
- You can change the messages on the "Select Destination Location" in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection). Change entries like `WizardSelectDir`, `SelectDirDesc`, `SelectDirLabel3` and `SelectDirBrowseLabel`.

```pascal
[Messages]
WizardSelectDir=Choose install directory

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  if not IsUpgrade then
  begin
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := '';
  end;
end;
```

For `IsUpgrade` function, see for example [Inno Setup: How to overwrite on install but not on change?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30566752/850848)

[image]

---

Or you can create a completely new custom page:
[How to ask the user to specify a folder name (using Inno Setup)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37883817/850848)

(and hide the standard one?)

Comment: thank yuou very much for your help, it works very well!

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk 3ds Max stores its installation directory in the Windows Registry.  You can set your Inno Setup installer to check that registry entry and use it as a default.

Here's a link to the 3ds Max SDK Programmer's Guide: [3ds Max Install Directory Registry Key](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/3ds-Max-SDK-Programmer-Guide/index.html?url=files/GUID-3D358AC5-F7BE-4A03-896B-ED92AFFD24E4.htm,topicNumber=d30e57200).